# Music missing from storage management

Tags: iphone, music, itunes-match

I am trying to purge the stored music on my iPhone 5s after canceling my Match subscription.

I've gone to "Settings > General > Usage > Manage Storage > Music" to do so and I simply cannot find Music. Other Apple apps are showing such as Podcasts and iBooks.

I've tried:

- Closing and reopening Settings
- Closing and reopening Music
- Shuffeling about "Show All Music" plus the above.
- Restarting the phone + above.

At a loss at what to do and would rather avoid a full reset of the device if possible.

Running IOS 8.3 Build 12F70 (current latest via OTA not a dev build)

Comment: Are you sure there is music remaining on the device? When you restarted, did you just power off/power on, or did you press and hold Sleep + Home until the Apple logo appeared?

Comment: I hadn't sleep + home'd, but have now and there's no change.

I am sure there is music on the device.  I've turned off show all music, my match sub has expired, and to be sure I've just turned to airplane mode.

Music shows up in music, and plays.  I am guessing this is mostl cached music from match as I've only ever downloaded 1 or 2 albums to device directly.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that there is no spinning wheel on top of the "Manage Storage" settings for if there is such a wheel, it indicates the loading of extra elements i.e. Music, Photos, etc. If you have lot's of Music i.e. above 4 or 5 GB, it could take time for the "Manage Storage" settings to bring the Music element on top.

As a last resort, you can simply sync an empty iTunes library with your iPhone and iTunes would do what it does best - it will wipe out the iPhone music library in no time. If you wonder how to open an empty iTunes library on your computer, see this: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201596